# subtitle selection in exoplayer not within screen bounds

Tags: android, android-tv, exoplayer2.x, leanback

Im trying to develop an android application for TV using exoplayer. Everything works fine in the emulator but when I try to run it on a physical device  the problems occurs.

TV is an running android 6 and have a resolution of (3840x2160)

When I press the CC button in the StyledPlayerView controller the subtitles selection goes out of the screen.

Here is my movvieplayer class and xml file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView;
import com.southpalmresort.sprtv.R;


public class MoviePlayer extends Activity {

    private ExoPlayer player;
    private StyledPlayerView playerView;

    private String movieUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movie_player);
        movieUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("movie_url");
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.movie_player_view);
        playerView.setShowSubtitleButton(true);




    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (movieUrl != null) {
            initializePlayer(movieUrl);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopPlayer();
    }

    private void initializePlayer(String url) {
        // Release the player if it already exists
        releasePlayer();

        // Create an ExoPlayer instance.
        player=new ExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        playerView.setUseController(true);


        // Set the player's listener.
        player.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int playbackState) {
                if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
                    // Exit the player when the movie ends.
                    stopPlayer();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

        // Prepare and play the media.
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(url);
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        player.prepare();
        player.play();
    }


    public void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }


    public void stopPlayer() {
// Check if the player is already stopped.
        if (player == null || !player.isPlaying()) {
            return;
        }

        player.stop();
        releasePlayer();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        stopPlayer();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layoutMode="clipBounds">


    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerControlView
        android:id="@+id/movie_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:show_next_button="false"
        app:show_subtitle_button="true" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Image from TV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XNDb.jpg)

when i run from the emulator it displays correctly.[Image from the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Xud.png)